# java stream comma separated

Tags: java, json, stream, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of strings. Each string represents json object like this for example:

```
// {"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}
String s1 = "{\"foo\": \"bar\", \"bar\": \"foo\"}";
```

I get a large amount of data from database that's why I'm using Stream.
And i want to stream this data to the output for http response.

```
try (Stream<String> data = service.streamData()) {
            os.write("[".getBytes());
            eventStream.forEach(s -> {
                        try {
                            os.write(s.getBytes());
                            os.write(",".getBytes());
                            os.write("\n".getBytes());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            logger.error(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
        }
        os.write("{}]".getBytes());
        os.flush();
```

Since each string represents a json object, I want to return an array of these objects. In this case I have to manually add `"["` and `"]"` and separate each element within the stream using comma. But eventually I will have a comma after the latest element as well. And this won't be a valid json.

It'd look like this:

```
["{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}", "{"foo": "bar1", "bar": "foo1"}",]
```

Any ideas how to get rid of the latest comma using stream?

Comment: The lame (but common) approach would be to not output the comma after every message, but to output it before each message (except for the first, which can be handled by a boolean).

Comment: Another lame (but common) approach would be to just append a dummy entry (assumes you can get the client code to ignore it).

Comment: Thilo, thank you for your answer, i kinda like your first proposal, could you tell me how can i check if the element is first when i use for each in stream?

Comment: You could have a StringBuilder, that in each iteration of the stream you either append `",\n"` to (if it is empty) or that you output (if it is not empty).

Comment: As a side note, `os.write("[".getBytes());`, `os.write(",".getBytes());` and `os.write("\n".getBytes());` are quite inefficient and unintentionally platform dependent ways of doing `os.write('[');`, `os.write(',');` and `os.write('\n');`…

Answer (score 2):

Note that while lambda expression are a neat feature, anonymous inner classes haven’t ceased to exist. In case you need a stateful consumer, they are the right tool. You don’t even need conditionals here:

```
stream.forEach(new Consumer<String>() {
    int header = '[';
    public void accept(String string) {
        try {
            os.write(header);
            os.write('\n');
            os.write(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            header=',';
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
os.write('\n');
os.write(']');
```

---

In case you have to handle empty streams, you may expand it to

```
os.write('[');
stream.forEach(new Consumer<String>() {
    int header = ' ';
    public void accept(String string) {
        try {
            os.write(header);
            os.write('\n');
            os.write(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            header=',';
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
os.write('\n');
os.write(']');
```